# Cannot connect to TFS server using TeamAddins in MonoDevelop 3.0.3.4 on Mac

Tags: macos, tfs, monodevelop

I am trying to connect to a TFS server from a mac using MonoDevelop 3.0.3.4 via the TeamAddins 3.0 plugin.

When I attempt to add my TFS repository, via Team -> Team Source Explorer -> Add Repository... and enter my TFS details, I receive in the Source Control pane:

Error: NameResolutionFailure

Error: NameResolutionFailure

Error: NameResolutionFailure

When I try to check out (via Version Control -> Checkout -> TeamFoundationServer) and enter my server's info, I receive the following exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at TeamAddins.VersionControl.TFS.TFSRepository.createNewWorkspace () [0x00000] in :0 
  at TeamAddins.VersionControl.TFS.TFSRepository.Checkout (FilePath path, MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Revision rev, Boolean recurse, IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.CheckoutWorker.Run () [0x00006] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-monodevelop-3.0.3-branch/57eb8135/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl/CheckoutCommand.cs:55 
  at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Task.BackgroundWorker (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-monodevelop-3.0.3-branch/57eb8135/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl/Task.cs:49

Any help would be much appreciated.  The TFS server I am attempting to connect to works OK from other IDEs and it is serving its content over http if that makes any difference.